# excel vba - sum up rows between 2 columns in a table

Tags: vba, excel

I have table in excel and would like to sum up all cells in the columns "count" and "restocked", and then have the result overwritten in the column "count" itself. Next the macro would then clear all existing values in the "restocked" column.

would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Please show us what code you already have and where that fails or needs improving.

Comment: Please understand that people are here to help/assist you to solve your issue yourself not to do the work for you and write the solution for you. So in general we need some code from you where we can show what is wrong and where to fix it. Also read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I would kindly ask you to research a little before asking your next question, as mentioned above. But I like the idea of people getting started on VBA so here it is:

```
Sub test()
'First you dimension two variables as Ranges    
Dim cnt As Range
Dim rstckd As Range
'You assign the Ranges to the variable 
Set cnt = Range("A2:A4")
Set rstckd = Range("B2:B4")
'To store the results you initialize an array to store the sums
Dim results()
'You redimension the results array to the number of entries in your table
ReDim results(1 To cnt.Rows.Count)
'You loop over your table and sum the values from count and restocked
For i = 1 To cnt.Rows.Count
    results(i) = cnt(i, 1) + rstckd(i, 1)
Next i
'You write the array to the range count and delete the values in restocjed
cnt = Application.Transpose(results)
rstckd.Clear

End Sub
```